# Getting information about short-lived processes

Tags: linux, process

I want to trace existing process and especially their parameters (like environment variables, cwd directory, stdout and so on). I can do it. However, I cannot get that information about short-lived processes). For example:

If I run:

```
sleep 120 & 
# get info from /proc/`pgrep sleep`
```

and it is easy.

But, what if my process is immediately terminated or I don't know PID of process (but I expect that some process will be created).

Answer (score 4):

One approach as an ordinary user is an `exec` wrapper, assuming the programs are run via a `PATH` search. That is, your wrapper for `program`

```
#!/bin/sh
env > /some/log/file
... (any other desired logging commands here) ...
exec /path/to/real/program "$@"
```

must exist first in `PATH`, so you might have `PATH=/some/wrapper/dir:$PATH` and then a wrapper `program` named exactly for the real `program` to be logged, and in the wrapper `program` you replace your wrapper with the original `program` using `exec`. If the program is being run by fully qualified paths then it may be necessary to fiddle around with something like `LD_PRELOAD` or perhaps the application in question may give an option to change the path?

As `root` tracing would be quite simple with something like `sysdig` ([various sysdig examples](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-Examples)) as that can match the ephemeral process names you are interested in, and can incrementally drill down to what you are interested in, say the program `ls` run as some user:

```
sudo sysdig "proc.name = ls and user.name = jhqdoe" | tee log
```

The rather verbose `log` file after an `ls` is run shows an `execve` entry that may give almost everything you need (the environment is truncated):

```
9734 16:12:49.683389228 1 ls (20542) < execve res=0 exe=ls args=--color=auto. tid=20542(ls) pid=20542(ls) ptid=20052(bash) cwd= fdlimit=1024 pgft_maj=0 pgft_min=61 vm_size=404 vm_rss=4 vm_swap=0 comm=ls cgroups=cpuset=/.cpu_cgroup=/.cpuacct=/.mem_cgroup=/.devices=/user.slice.freezer=/.ne... env=XDG_SESSION_ID...
```

Via the [user guide](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-User-Guide) and other documentation, the above can be made precise to only the `execve` call and the full environment shown via:

```
sudo sysdig -p "%proc.env" "proc.name = ls and user.name = jhqdoe and evt.type = execve" | tee xxx
```

Adjust `-p` to show what you want; you could also use a chisel to extract what you want from a live capture or a save file, etc.

Comment: I second sysdig +1

Comment: `sysdig` is great but how to get information about stdout, stderr and stdin?

Comment: what sort of information about those descriptors? dipping into them can be problematical given how they can be shared between processes

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use [`forkstat(1)`](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/forkstat/) or some other program using the [proc connector](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9f46080c41d5f3f7c00b4e169ba4b0b2865258bf) interface. Unfortunately, you can only do that as root. Also, `forkstat(1)` isn't extensible or scriptable, so you'll probably have to write your own program combining the data from the proc connector with that from `procfs` if you also want it to print the environment of a process, its controlling tty, etc.

Here is a very crude way to "extend" `forkstat(1)` to also print the actual path to the binary and the current directory of a process upon `execve`:

```
stdbuf -o0 forkstat -e fork,exec | perl -anle '
  print;
  if($F[1] eq "exec"){
     print "\texe = ", readlink "/proc/$F[2]/exe";
     print "\tcwd = ", readlink "/proc/$F[2]/cwd";
  }
'
```

As an ordinary user, your only solution is run the parent process starting those short-lived processes (or one of its ancestors) via

```
strace -s1024 -vfe trace=execve prog args ...
```

The `-s` option controls how much of the argv and env strings `strace` will print. Running programs via `strace` may have quite an impact on performance. There may be other more friendly / scriptable alternatives to `strace(1)`, but they all have to use `ptrace(2)` if they are to be used by an ordinary user, so don't expect them to be essentially different.