# Find child processes created by a Command?

Tags: linux

Is there a way in Linux to check the child processes created by a command? I am running a command and it completes execution within 1 second. In this duration, it is difficult for me to analyse the process tree using the ps command to check any child processes created by the command.

Is there another way to do this in Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: `strace -fe trace=clone,fork,execve`, [`forkstat`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499653/getting-information-about-short-lived-processes/499654#499654)

Comment: As mosvy suggested, `strace` is incredibly useful, here. The array of optional flags/arguments can be a bit bewildering. While you can (and should) use `man strace` to learn about the command(s)... it's both "okay" and often easier to use a web search with the command (e.g., strace) and what you'd like to accomplish.

If you find a solution that works for you, it's a nice gesture to post that solution as part of the (this) thread.

Technically, all of the process data is contained under the `/proc` filesystem in Linux. However, following that "chain" yourself isn't necessarily easy.